# Fatal Error Detected! Failed to execute script

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe, executable, execute

I'm very new to coding and just started recently. I made a very basic calculator and tried to make it into an exe file so that I could run it on a system without python. But after making it into an exe file using pyinstaller, it says it cannot execute script. Please help!

````
print("Welcome to Subahs Calculator")
print("Choose an operation to perform:")
print("1.Addition")
print("2.Substraction")
print("3.Multiplication")
print("4.Division")
print("5.Square")
print("6.Square Root")

operation = input()

if operation == "1":
    num1 = input("Enter first number: ")
    num2 = input("Enter second number: ")
    result = float(num1) + float(num2)
    print("The result is " + str(result))
elif operation == "2":
    num1 = input("Enter first number: ")
    num2 = input("Enter second number: ")
    result = float(num1) - float(num2)
    print("The result is " + str(result))
elif operation == "3":
    num1 = input("Enter first number: ")
    num2 = input("Enter second number: ")
    result = float(num1) * float(num2)
    print("The result is " + str(result))
elif operation == "4":
    num1 = input("Enter first number: ")
    num2 = input("Enter second number: ")
    result = float(num1) / float(num2)
    print("The result is " + str(result))
elif operation == "5":
    num1 = input("Enter the number: ")
    result = pow(float(num1), 2)
    print("The result is " + str(result))
elif operation == "6":
    num1 = input("Enter the number: ")
    result = sqrt(float(num1))
    print("The result is " + str(result))
else: print("Invalid Operation")

k = input("Press Enter to exit.")```
````

Comment: what command did you use to create exe file?

Comment: pyinstaller --onefile -w

Comment: Try without -w flag and edit the post with the error in CMD or console

Comment: It seemed to have worked because I didn't add -w, thanks for the help!